# Upgrade PowerShell version Remotely on Win Server 2012 R2

Tags: azure-powershell

I would like to know is there any way of upgrading the PowerShell version remotely (i.e. using Run command option)  from 4.0 to 5.1 on the Win Server 2012 R2 VMs.

The reason is that I'm trying to eliminate the dependency of restarting VM after upgrade as that will impact production applications which are running in there. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update Powershell version from `4.0` to `5.1` on Win Server 2012 R2 VM remotely, follow the steps below.

1.Store the script as `testinstall.ps1` in local, it will download the `.msu` update file, then install it.

```
$url = "https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/F/5/6F5FF66C-6775-42B0-86C4-47D41F2DA187/Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3191564-x64.msu"
$outpath = "D:/psinstall.msu"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $outpath

wusa.exe D:\psinstall.msu /quiet /norestart
```

2.Use `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand` to run the script remotely in the VM.

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName "<group-name>" -VMName "<VM-name>" -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath 'C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\testinstall.ps1'
```

[image]

**Note**: After update the powershell version, anyway we need to restart the VM, otherwise it will not take affect, you could restart it in the portal or use powershell.

```
Restart-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "<group-name>" -Name "<VM-name>"
```

Check the result in the VM:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I agree with your first part but can't we just eliminate the dependency of the restart because that is what stopping me in doing this - I can't afford restart of the VMs. Though you do it remotely or manually. we must restart the machine isn't it ?

Comment: @praveenkrish You must restart the VM, no other options, the `.msu` file is a windows update file, just like a windows update, if you don't restart the VM, it will not take effect.

Comment: @YonWang Got it but still it would have been good if we can do it forcefully kinda.